# WPF MenuItem Padding Style is not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set *Padding* to a *MenuItem* via *Style* as:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}"
    TargetType="MenuItem"
    x:Key="MainMenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>

<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Menu" Style="{StaticResource MainMenuItem}" />
</Menu>
```

In here the `Background` of the MenuItem is changing but not the `Padding`

See below:

[image]

But if I change the Padding directly as follows then it changes correctly:

`<MenuItem Header="Menu" Style="{StaticResource MainMenuItem}" Padding="10" />`

[image]

How can I get the *MenuItem Padding* to work via *Style*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem"
                   x:Key="MainMenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Menu" Style="{StaticResource MainMenuItem}"/>
    </Menu>
```